# Laravel transform not working as intended on collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection which is an eloquent query.

There is **one column where I want to replace the value with another value**.

I am using the **transform** function to do this however it is not working as intended.

Here is my **query** in the controller :

```
    $articles = KnowledgeBaseArticle::getArticlesByDepartment($department)
        ->get()
        ->transform(function ($article) {
          $article->category_id = KnowledgeBaseCategory::find($article->category_id)->name;
        });
```

And the `getArticlesByDepartment` **query from the model**:

```
    public function scopeGetArticlesByDepartment($query, $department){
                return $query->where('department', $department)
                            ->select('title', 'updated_at', 'department', 'id', 'category_id')
                            ->orderBy('title', 'asc');
    }
```

I want to return it so that all the rows with column `category_id` is replaced with the category name. You can see I am trying to do this by using `$article->category_id` by using find on the KnowledgeBaseCategory model to retrieve this. However this is not working at all and when I die and dump, I get an single column array full of nulls.

When I have died and dumped `$article->category_id` & find query inside the transform, it is returning the correct category name, it is just not replacing the `category_id` column with the category name.

I have also tried map instead of transform and got the same result.

If it matters, I am later on converting this data into JSON.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have a relationship set up for the category instead of doing a find on the category_id in your controller?

Comment: Because I am trying to get this part to work before I refactor into cleaner code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform, not unlike map, needs you to return the modified item of the collection, as this will replace the existing item.

```
transform(function ($article) {
    $article->category_id = KnowledgeBaseCategory::find($article->category_id)->name;
    return $article;
});
```

Since objects are mutable and passed by reference, you can just do this in an each() closure instead to save a line:

```
each(function ($article) {
    $article->category_id = KnowledgeBaseCategory::find($article->category_id)->name;
});
```

Though, you really should have a relationship set up for category.  There's no reason to be performing this find logic in your controller.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, I did think it was something simple I missed.